# Storing superpixels in a more easily accessible format for computation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am attempting to find and store superpixels in an image in a vector for easier access. However when trying to store these structs in a vector I consistently get runtime errors regarding memory corruptions or core abortions.

```
typedef struct SuperPixel {
  vector<Point2i> pixels;
  /*
  Other fields needed
  */
} SuperPixel;

int main() {
  string image_location = "/home/jake/original.jpg";
  Mat img = imread(image_location, IMREAD_COLOR);
  cv::Size half(img.cols / 2, img.rows / 2);
  cv::resize(img, img, half);
  vector<SuperPixel> superpixels;
  Ptr<ximgproc::SuperpixelSLIC> SP =
      ximgproc::createSuperpixelSLIC(img, ximgproc::SLICO, 40);
  Mat labels;
  SP->getLabels(labels);
  int N = SP->getNumberOfSuperpixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    SuperPixel sp;
    superpixels.push_back(sp);
  }
  labels.forEach<int>([&](int& pixel, const int* position) -> void {
    Point2i p(position[0], position[1]);
    superpixels[pixel].pixels.push_back(p);
  });
}
```

I have tried not using structs, but just storing them as 
 a `vector<vector<Point2i>>` but I run into the same errors consistently

Comment: You're using C++, don't do `typedef struct X {} X;`. Instead, just do `struct X {};`

Comment: Add an `assert(pixel < N)` to your `forEach` loop. I don't know if this is guaranteed or not, my guess this is your problem.

Comment: One more simplification: your first loop is the same as `superpixels.resize(N)`, but less efficient.